# How to populate/create new classes from Strings/html data? JAVA

Tags: java, android, class, populate

Suppose I have a bunch of Strings, I need to now create/write new classes from all of the data. For example, let's say I have the formatted String data here with two items that need to be created:

```
STAMINA
    You have an amazing amount of stamina. 

PREREQUISITE: Health 13 

BENEFIT: You recover vitality points twice as fast as normal. So, if
    you would normally recover 1 hp per level per hour, 
    with this feat you recover 2 hp per level per hour. A 
    ******* character with this feat recovers 4 hp per 
    level per hour. 

CHITINOUS
    You have especially thick armor for a member of your species.

PREREQUISITE: Health 13, damage reduction as a species trait

BENEFIT: The damage reduction you receive as a species trait is 
    increased by 1. This bonus does not apply 
    to DR imparted by equipment.

SPECIAL: This feat can be selected multiple times. Each time you 
    select it, its effects stack.
```

By this time, this has been added to a hashmap, with the Feat title/name as the key and the rest of the data as a String for the value.

What I need to do now is create new class files for each "Feat", *Stamina* and *Chitnous*. So after grabbing the *Stamina* key and its value (everything after Stamina) from the map, the above data would then result in something like below.

First, a Stamina class that extends the abstract Feat class.

```
public class Stamina extends Feat {
  public Stamina() {
    super("STAMINA", "You have an amazing amount of stamina.\n" +
          "    PREREQUISITE: Health 13\n" + 
          "    BENEFIT: You recover hp twice as fast as normal. So,
          if you would normally recover 1 hp per level per hour, 
          with this feat you recover 2 hp per level per hour. 
          A ******* character with this feat recovers 4 hp points per 
          level per hour.");
    prereqs.put("CON", 13);//This is a method that populates when seeing "PREREQUISITE" in the String
    }
  }
```

Notice there is an additional line that calls a helper method in addition to the call to *super(String name, String data)*.

After this, the algorithm should generate another class file *Chitnous* and put it in the same directory as the new *Stamina* class file, however it'd be superfluous for me to write out that example.

**Thanks in advance!**

TL:DR How do I take Strings and from them write new class files to a target directory in my Android project? To be clear I don't need to initialize objects, I'm trying to populate code from Strings. This would happen in a singleton method/only ever happen once.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, thanks for showing interest in my problem. So far I have not automated this process as I lack the knowledge to write code that writes code. I have simply been manually writing the classes, though there are hundreds of classes yet to write.